# Praxis Is to doing as <fill in> is to being. Please solve this analogy

Tags: etymology

Please solve this analogy involving Greek? Etymology.

Comment: *On*, as in *on kai me on*, "being and non-being"

Answer (score 1):

Praxis is to doing as existence is to being?

Comment: Could you add a citation showing how this works?

Comment: Not really, it's just off the of of my head. According to my friend Wikipedia, "In Ancient Greek the word praxis (πρᾶξις) referred to activity engaged in by free people. The philosopher Aristotle held that there were three basic activities of humans: theoria (thinking), poiesis (making), and praxis (doing)." Hence, my suggestion of the relationship between "existence" and "being" being similar, albeit tenuous (which is why I included the final "?").

Comment: Well that comment clears what may or may not have been lacking in the answer

Comment: Point taken. I'm quite new to the site and unaccustomed to such academic rigour online.

Comment: To be honest this question isn't a great one but your answer is better than most first posts

Comment: I just did a quick lookup (which the questioner could have done) and came up with *einai* as the Greek for "to be."

Comment: This question is about the Greek language, not English. The answer is going to be a Greek word.

Comment: Thank you Nigel where was the appropriate place to post this I will delete it and do so.